# how to remove all body classes in wordpress

Tags: page-template, body-class

i am working on custom page templates. so i want to remove all body classes by one function only.
i searched it for on net but not found any solution.

is there anyone who can answer it. @Php

Edit..

how to remove all page template classes except all other..

example - page-template, page-template-zx, page-template-zx-php etc. means all classes that starts with "page" word.

problem is that i am using many page templates so i want to do this with one function from pasting in functions.php

Comment: Which classes in particular do you mean?

Comment: classes of body tag in wordpress, dude.

Comment: @E-Gyan why do you want to do this? page templates themselves are a html class on the body tag, you can use that to write CSS rules that eliminate any potential conflicts. Note that any answer you get won't be a copy pasta, you will need a basic understanding of programming to use the answers you get here

Comment: @TomJNowell and i have enought programming knowledge to use them sir

Comment: @TomJNowell if you can then please answer it.\

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume you mean the classes generated by [body_class()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/), e.g. from the twentytwentyone header.php:

```php
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
```

The simplest thing to do is to just remove the `<?php body_class(); ?>` call from your header.php. Or if you can't / don't want to change that, create a new header.php for these pages e.g. header-custom.php and load this with `wp_head('custom')` in your template.

Or if you really do need to suppress the output of body_class() then you can filter that away:

```php
function empty_body_class($classes, $class) {
    return [];
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'empty_body_class', 999, 2 );
```

but you'll probably be left with an empty `class=""` on the body tag.

---

Or (as you've asked in comments) if you just want to remove anything starting "page", or a fixed string "example_class", you can just edit the array in the filter instead e.g.

```php
function filter_body_classes( $classes, $class ) {
    foreach( $classes as $key => $value ) {
        if ( strpos( $value, 'page' ) === 0
             || $value === 'example_class' ) {
            unset( $classes[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'filter_body_classes', 999, 2 );
```

Comment: how to remove all  page template classes except all other

Comment: example - page-template, page-template-zx, page-template-zx-php etc. means all classes that starts with "page" word

Comment: problem is that i am using many page templates so i want to do this with one function from pasting in functions.php

Comment: Just change the string I'm testing for in the strpos line then

Comment: now what changes i have to made your last function if i want to remove another class like "example_class"

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Rup should answer your question. As you've asked in comments "what changes I have to made your last function if I want to remove another class like 'example_class'", you can just edit the line I have mentioned in my following code:

```
function filter_body_classes( $classes, $class ) {
    foreach( $classes as $key => $value ) {
        if ( strpos( $value, 'page' ) === 0
             || $value === 'example_class' || $value === 'example_class_two' || $value === 'example_class_three' ) { //add as many example_class as you need like this
            unset( $classes[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'filter_body_classes', 999, 2 );
```